# How to sync or copy only modified and newly added files to GCS bucket using gsutil rsync from local folder?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to copy or sync newly added or modified files only from local folder to GCS bucket using rsync, It looks like rsync is copying all the files again to gcs buckets instead of copying updated or newly added files.

The command I am using right now :
gsutil -m rsync -r -d ./data/ gs://bucket/data/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `-n` flag to your command, example `gsutil -m rsync -r -d -n gs://source-bucket gs://destination-bucket`?