# Sync Images from google server disk to Bucket

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, rsync, bucket, gsutil

We are copying the images and documents from our local Ubuntu server to the Google bucket using the below command.
gsutil -m rsync -a public-read -R -C -f /media/data_disk/ITEM/ gs://dev-cdn-assets-com/ITEM

The command is copying only the new images or Documents to the CDN server, if an image already exists with the same name then it will not copy.  We should copy the updated images with the same name.  Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I don't know what the -f option. Read this for the change. It should work today: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#change-detection-algorithm

Comment: Provide details on an object that does not copy. Specifically, the dates, sizes, and checksums of the two objects. Try adding the `-c` flag to use checksums instead of dates for change comparison.

Comment: Have you seen the above comments?Also Can you try `gsutil -m rsync -r -d -n gs://source-bucket gs://destination-bucket` as  suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74881060/how-to-sync-or-copy-only-modified-and-newly-added-files-to-gcs-bucket-using-gsut)

Comment: Hi @user2693302 Can you try the above command and check if it's working for you or not